# Android CheckBox onClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, checkbox

May be this duplicate question but I didn't find answer for me.

My `ClickListener` for `CheckBox` doesn't work.

This xml:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_visibility"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mat_card_padding"/>
```

This code from Activity:

```
        mVisibilityCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_visibility);
        mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // this method doesn't call
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "isChecked - " + mVisibilityCheckBox.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

**UPD** I add code from answer - but this doesn't work for me(

```
mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // this doesn't work
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "isChecked - " + mVisibilityCheckBox.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: You have to add setOnCheckedChangeListener instead of setOnClickListener for checkbox.

Comment: @HareshChhelana i try it, but this doen't work for me(

Comment: try to check if you are testing the correct CheckBox or layout. may be ID conflicts. Is it changing its state or not?

Comment: Can you post your full xml code?

Comment: @Rami full xml code very big )

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko Because maybe there is a parent view of your checkbox that consumes the click event.

Comment: @Rami - http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/0004/0191/303295/151117/949348421b.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
           Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "isChecked - " + mVisibilityCheckBox.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: try use this mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       }
   }
);

Comment: check now code is different i added new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() insted just OnCheckedChangeListener()

Answer (score 2):

check this example.this could help you.
http://www.bipinrupadiya.com/2013/08/android-checkbox-setoncheckedchangelist.html

**Edited:**
the code required here is shown below:

```
CheckBox hin = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkHindi);
hin.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check box "+arg0.getText().toString()+" is "+String.valueOf(arg1) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
  } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(satView.isChecked()){

                System.out.println("Checked");

            }else{

                System.out.println("Un-Checked");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this code and it will work

```
mVisibilityCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (mVisibilityCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                // this doesn't work
                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "isChecked - " + mVisibilityCheckBox.isChecked(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply add `clickable="true"` in CheckBox xml.

For example :

```
<CheckBox
     android:id="@+id/checkbox_visibility"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mat_card_padding"
     android:clickable="true"/>
```